# how to iterate through all the blob names from subdirectories as well, in Azure Cloud Storage using python?

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cloud-services, azure-container-service

**Objective** : to iterate and write all the blobs from root and multiple sub-directories present.

this is current code written:

```
for _file in container_client.walk_blobs(include='metadata'):
            file_name = 'file.txt'
            f = open(file_name, 'a+') 
            with open(file_name, 'r') as sample:
                read_sample = sample.read()
                if not re.search(_file.name, read_sample):
                    print('New One')
                    f.write(_file.name + os.linesep)
                    f.close()
```

- the above code just returns blob names from root directory.

I was able to extract blobs from specific directory, but not all sub-directories present.

How do I get the blob names present in all sub-directories as well? Thanks for the help !

Comment: In Azure blob storage,  it does not contain `Directory`. If you want to get one blob,, we can directly use the name like `root/sub-folder/sample.txt`.

Comment: yes, you're right. but is it possible to iterate through all the sub-folders present and get the blobs present there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to list blobs in one directory, please refer to the following code

```
def walk_blob_hierarchy(prefix=""):
        nonlocal depth
        for item in container_client.walk_blobs(name_starts_with=prefix):
           
            if isinstance(item, BlobPrefix):                    
                walk_blob_hierarchy(prefix=item.name)
               
            else:
              
                print(item.name)
walk_blob_hierarchy(prefix="<folder name>")
```

For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-list?tabs=python) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs)